# Olap cube and MDX and NON EMPTY

Tags: t-sql, ssas, mdx, olap

I am pretty new to SSAS, OLAP and MDX syntax.

So I have this `MDX` to query the cube by `TSQL` (by linked server to SSAS) and it works fine:

```
select * from openquery(GCUBE, 
'SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Valore] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {
( [Prodotti].[Top Marca].[Top Marca].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Prodotti].[Top Codice].[Top Codice].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Agenti].[Vw Agenti].[Vw Agenti].ALLMEMBERS
* [Calendario].[AnnoMese].[Mese].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Prodotti].[Ordinamento].[Ordinamento].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Prodotti].[Top].[Top].ALLMEMBERS )
}
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION
ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Calendario].[Anno].&[2012] } )
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Agenti].[Vw Agenti].&[005] } )
ON COLUMNS FROM [Vendite])) WHERE (  [Calendario].[Anno].&[2012] )'
)
```

Well, the `[Prodotti].[Top Marca]` is a dimension based on a table with the 50 top selling brands and this MDX is filtered by a specific ID Agent `[Vw Agenti] = 005`.

The purpose of the query is to find out **how the agent is selling the company's 50 top selling brands.**

The query works fine but there is one brand not sold by this agent and I need to show the empty row.

The figure below shows the **missing record relative to the position (rank) 31**.

[image: MDX Query result]

I understand the concept about `NON EMPTY` but I can't find the right syntax to also show the empty record.

How should I modify the MDX?

I tried to remove `NON EMPTY` but I get a generic error:

```
Cannot execute the query against OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "GCUBE"
```

Do I need to change the dimension `Top Marca` in the cube?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me or give the right tips to solve this.

Comment: What is the error when removing the NON EMPTY ?

Comment: @Marc, i added more information about the error but as you can see is a generic error

Comment: Why are you asking for Agenti on both columns and rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a specialist of SSAS/TSQL, but I would try a simple request first :

```
SELECT 

[Measures].[Valore]ON COLUMNS, 

NON EMPTY [Prodotti].[Top Marca].[Top Marca].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS 

FROM ( SELECT { [Calendario].[Anno].&[2012] } ON COLUMNS 
  FROM ( SELECT { [Agenti].[Vw Agenti].&[005] } ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [Vendite] 
  )
) '
```

Any way to run it without this TSQL stuff?

Comment: +1 for starting simple. This is almost always the best way to get complex MDX queries figured out. Get something basic working and then layer on complexity. You'll identify puzzling issues 1 at a time as you add to your query rather than having 50 different candidates that could be the cause of your problem.